# Characterization of risk factors for a very rare condition

Tags: biostatistics, small-sample, risk, rare-events, case-cohort

I am looking at a cohort of patients including 13000 patients, out of which only 160 have condition A. Out of these patients, only 6 have condition B. I would like to be able to characterize those with condition B versus those without condition B (out of the 160) in some way (I have a variety of clinical and demographic variables for these patients). The problem is that the lowest P value attainable for such a small cohort is 0.1 (e.g. in a Fisher exact test where say 3 patients are males and 3 are females).

Is there any hope to be able to say something meaningful about these 6 patients? And if so in what way?

Comment: P values and "meaningful" are not related concepts.  Could you clarify, then, what connection you conceive of between them?